# Error al crear un indice FULLTEXT sql server

Tags: sql-server

Buen día.

Estoy intentando crear un indice `full text` con la siguiente estructura

El catalogo ya esta creado

```
CREATE TABLE descr (
id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY not null,
descripcion NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS UNIQUE not null,
caracteristicas NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS UNIQUE not null
);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON descr (
descripcion LANGUAGE 1033,
caracteristicas LANGUAGE 1033
) KEY INDEX PK_descripciones ON ftCatalogo;
GO
```

Ahora , despues de ejecutar obtengo

> Msg 7653, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
> 'PK_descripciones' no es un índice válido para aplicar una clave de búsqueda de texto completo. Una clave de búsqueda de texto completo debe ser un índice único de una columna que no admita valores NULL, que no esté sin conexión, que no esté definida en una columna calculada no determinista o no persistente e imprecisa, que no tenga un filtro y que tenga un tamaño máximo de 900 bytes. Elija otro índice para la clave de texto completo.

Por favor una explicacion

Comment: Hola, Joan. Una explicación? Claro. Parece que PK_descripciones no es un índice válido para aplicar una clave de búsqueda de texto completo. Una clave de búsqueda de texto completo debe ser un índice único de una columna que no admita valores NULL, que no esté sin conexión, que no esté definida en una columna calculada no determinista o no persistente e imprecisa, que no tenga un filtro y que tenga un tamaño máximo de 900 bytes. Tal vez quieras revisar la documentación oficial de sqlserver para comprender completamente cómo crear ese tipo de índices.

Comment: Difícil decir, no sé que sea `PK_descripciones`, pero no es parte de las cosas que se crean en el script que publicas como parte de la pregunta. Entiendo que tu intención sería usar la llave primaria de la tabla como índice, pero lo cierto es que la llave primaria de esa tabla tiene un nombre  puesto por SQL Server y que, seguramente, no es `PK_descripciones`, por tanto diría que no estás usando el índice que tu crees estar usando, sino que (por casualidad) existe en tu base de datos con este nombre, pero probablemente pertenece a otra tabla o de verdad no cumple con las especificaciones.

Comment: Incluye la sentencia de creación de dicho índice en el script y podremos decirlo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás creando la llave primaria sobre la cual trabajará el índice full text. O mejor dicho, estás creando una pero no la estás nombrando. Lo único que necesitas hacer es nombrar la llave primaria.

```
CREATE TABLE descr (
id INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_caracteristicas PRIMARY KEY not null,
descripcion NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS UNIQUE not null,
caracteristicas NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS UNIQUE not null,

);
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON descr (
    descripcion LANGUAGE 1033,
    caracteristicas LANGUAGE 1033
) KEY INDEX PK_caracteristicas ON ftCatalogo;
GO
```

Por cierto, ten cuidado si estás usando COLLATE en tus columnas. Es posible obtener errores de incompatibilidad si el valor es distinto al del servidor y las tablas del sistema.